# Is it possible to decorate a class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

How to collect information about the class attributes while the class is being constructed?

In Java, what I am asking for is possible.

In Python, that doesn't seem to be the case. Correct me if I am wrong!

I am constructing a sqlalchemy object that is defined declaratively.

```
class Foo(BASE):
   id = Column(Integer, primaryKey=True, nullable=False)
   text = Column(String(100))
```

I would like to define the class like this:

```
class Foo(declarative_base()):
   @persisted_property(id=true)
   id = Column(Integer, primaryKey=True, nullable=False)

   @persisted_property(mutable=True)
   text = Column(String(100))

   @persisted_property(set_once=True)
   created_by = Column(Integer)

   @classmethod
   def builder(cls, existing=None):
       return Builder(cls, existing)
```

The `persisted_property` class/function/? purpose is to collect the class attributes. 
With that knowledge, these things would happen:

1. a `builder()` classmethod would be added to the class `Foo` that returns a generated FooBuilder. The `FooBuilder` would have these methods: `set_text()->FooBuilder`, `set_created_by()->FooBuilder`, `build()->Foo`
2. (ideally) any attempt to directly alter a `Foo` object would be blocked. (how to let sqlalchemy work?)

Example behavior:

1. `Foo.builder().set_text("Foo text").set_created_by(1).build()`
2. `Foo.builder(existing_foo).set_text("Foo text").set_created_by(1).build()` : would raise Exception since `existing_foo` already has a value for `created_by`

Notes:

1. Adding a class level decorator separates the attribute definition from the decoration and feels ... wrong
2. Class level decorations happen after sqlalchemy does it magic. (this could be good or bad)

Alternatives? suggestions?

Comment: Note that Python is *not Java*. You are thinking too much in terms of Java immutable types. Don't try to replicate that pattern in Python; go with the normal SQLAlchemy flow instead.

Comment: Side note: don't use `declarative_base()` directly as the base class. Assign it in your project and *use the assigned reference* as the base class. Otherwise you end up generating multiple bases and won't be able to access the shared table definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@callable` decorator syntax is indeed exclusive to `def` function and `class` class statements. However, it is just *syntactic sugar*.

The syntax

```
@name(arguments)
def functionname(...):
    # ...
```

is translated to:

```
def functionname(...):
    # ...
functionname = name(arguments)(functionname)
```

that is, the callable object produced by `@[decorator]` is called and the result is assigned back to the function name (or class name, if applied to a `class` statement).

You can always call the decorator directly, and assign the return value:

```
id = persisted_property(id=true)(Column(Integer, primaryKey=True, nullable=False))
```

However, decorators do not have access to the namespace in which the objects are constructed! The body of a `class` statement is executed as if it were a function (albeit with different scoping rules) and the resulting local namespace is taken to produce the class attributes. A decorator is just another function call in this context, and the local namespace of the class body is not meant to be available.

Next, I'd not even begin to build your *builder pattern*. That's a Java pattern where class privacy and immutability are enforced to the detriment of dynamic language patterns. Python is not Java, don't try to turn it into Java. For example, you can't really make instances of Python classes immutable, that's simply not something a dynamic language lets you do. Moreover, the  builder pattern is a solution to a problem that doesn’t really exist in Python, where you can build up your arguments to construct a class up front in, say, a dictionary you then apply dynamically to a class call, whereas Java has no such dynamic call support.

And you don't need to use a decorator pattern to mark your schema attributes *anyway*. You should instead rely on SQLAlchemy's own [introspection support](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/inspection.html):

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

class Builder:
    def __init__(self, cls, existing=None, **attrs):
        self.cls = cls
        if existing is not None:
            assert isinstance(existing, cls)
            existing_attrs = {n: s.value for n, s in inspect(existing).attrs.items()}
            # keyword arguments override existing attribute values
            attrs = {**existing_attrs, **attrs}
        self.attrs = attrs
    def _create_attr_setter(self, attrname):
        # create a bound attribute setter for the given attribute name
        def attr_setter(self, value):
            if attrname in self.attrs:
                raise ValueError(f"{attrname} already has a value set")
            return type(self)(self.cls, **self.attrs, **{attrname: value})
        attr_setter.__name__ = f'set_{attrname}'
        return attr_setter.__get__(self, type(self))
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.startswith('set_'):
            attrname = name[4:]
            mapper = inspect(self.cls)
            # valid SQLAlchemy descriptor name on the class?
            if attrname in mapper.attrs:
                return self._create_attr_setter(attrname)
        raise AttributeError(name)
    def build(self):
        return self.cls(**self.attrs)

class BuilderMixin:
    @classmethod
    def builder(cls, existing=None):
        return Builder(cls, existing)
```

and then just use `BuilderMixin` as a mixin class:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
>>> from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
>>> Base = declarative_base()
>>> class Foo(Base, BuilderMixin):
...     __tablename__ = 'foo'
...     id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
...     text = Column(String(100))
...     created_by = Column(Integer)
...
>>> Foo.builder().set_text('Demonstration text').set_created_by(1).build()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x10f8314a8>
>>> _.text, _.created_by
('Demonstration text', 1)
```

You can attach additional information to columns in the `info` dictionary:

```
text = Column(String(100), info={'mutable': True})
```

which your builder code could then access via the mapper (e.g. `mapper.attrs['text'].info.get('mutable', False)`).

But again, rather than recreate the Java builder pattern, just construct the `attrs` dictionary directly, and at most encode mutability rules by using a [hybrid property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) or with [ORM events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/event.html).

Comment: Thx. This helps an enormous amount. Tracing through this execution I learned a lot! There is a bug when building from an existing object. `inspect(existing).dict` returns an object with the only key as `_sa_instance_state`. I am not familiar enough with sqlalchemy/python yet know the solution. Maybe you know?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected to test that part, and forgot that the instance dictionary won’t hold the values directly. I’ve updated that part to use the `attrs` namespace instead. Still untested (on mobile right now).

Comment: Thx, Martijn. The builder pattern makes it much easier to enforce business rules and permissions on what can be mutated and by whom. If everything has to go through a builder, it makes it easy to add/subtract rules.

Comment: @Pat: that's why I pointed to ORM events; you can achieve the same results without breaking established Python and SQLAlchemy patterns. That'll make it much easier for other experienced Python developers to get up and running with your project.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from functools import partial


class BaseDecorator(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def decorate(self, method, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def __call__(self, method):
        class Wrapper(object):
            def __init__(self, parent, method):
                self.method = method
                self.parent = parent

            def __call__(self, obj, *args, **kwargs):
                return self.parent.decorate(self.method, obj, *args, **kwargs)

            def __get__(self, obj, cls):
                return partial(self.__call__, obj)
        return Wrapper(self, method)


class SomeDecorator(BaseDecorator):
    def __init__(self, goto=None):
        self.goto = goto

    def decorate(self, method, obj, *args, **kwargs):
        print("method was decorated")
        return method(obj, *args, **kwargs)


class Foo(object):
    @SomeDecorator(goto='/promo/')
    def get(self, request):
        return 'response'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Foo()
    print(foo.get('/layout/'))
```